# Inconsistency in moment subtract method

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the names of the last three months using momentJS. The method I am following is as follows:

```
var currentDate = moment();
[currentDate.format('MMMM'),
currentDate.subtract(1, 'months').format('MMMM'),
currentDate.subtract(2, 'months').format('MMMM')]
```

This works fine except for one problem. When the current date is in February. The list of months I get is : `['February', 'January', 'November']`, when the last element should be `December`. Is this correct?or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Moment is poorly designed, and mutates everything in place. You're subtracting from currentDate twice, which mutates currentDate

Comment: just subtract `1` too for third month

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine

```
[moment().format('MMMM'),
moment().subtract(1, 'months').format('MMMM'),
moment().subtract(2, 'months').format('MMMM')]
```

When you do

```
currentDate.subtract(1, 'months').format('MMMM')
```

your `currentDate` becomes = January

and then when you do

```
currentDate.subtract(2, 'months').format('MMMM')
```

it subtracts two months from January which is November